Why are Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC) snapshots on my external APFS drive during First Aid?
I ran First Aid on an external APFS-formatted HDD using Disk Utility on macOS. During the process, I noticed that the logs mention snapshots with the prefix “com.bombich.ccc”. However, I’ve never installed Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC) on this mac.
Some utility of CCC are now integrated in macOS?
Here is the original log from the First Aid operation:
Running First Aid on “HDP4T” (disk7s1)

Checking file system and repairing if necessary and if possible.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/rdisk7s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 270336.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the encryption key structures.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk7s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume HDP4T was formatted by diskmanagementd (1934.141.2) and last modified by apfs_kext (2236.141.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 2 (com.bombich.ccc.1C1742C1-E7CF-4A10-8582-618073CE1F55.2023-05-21-012810, transaction ID 401)
Checking snapshot 2 of 2 (com.bombich.ccc.DBB64824-DB7F-4913-960E-941F6FD9BED1.2023-05-21-040505, transaction ID 432)
Checking the document ID tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
Verifying allocated space.
The volume /dev/rdisk7s1 with UUID 15436CBB-C656-4717-8FE8-66711F56D884 appears to be OK.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.

Operation successful.```


No CCC is not part of macOS. The logical answer is you connected that drive to a Mac at some point and it made snapshots. If that’s the extent of your question, I came make it a proper answer.

@bmike CCC has to be told to put snapshots on a specific volume, either as part of the setup to be a backup destination, or as a CCC controlled regular snapshot independent from a backup. It then does so as per schedule Not sure CCC would make snapshots on just any connected volume without confirmation. I only have CCC snapshots enabled on my CCC destinations, my non-CCC externals do not have CCC snapshots. OP, is the volume newly formatted on your machine? The snapshots will have a date & time associated with them. Does that tally with any particular event?

Just to be clear, to create snapshots requires a special capability from Apple.  At some point CCC has certainly operated on that APFS volume.  Get the date and times from Disk Utility (Menu: View > Show APFS snapshots).
